# How to skip control when we are using scanner readLine() when user is nothing entered from keyboard?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My code is :

```
System.out.print("press key Y or N to run the test");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = null;
input = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: execution should not be close.. Only control need to skip from scanner readline

Comment: Never use comments to add more content for the question. Just update the question.

Comment: and where exactly you want to control to go !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do. `nextLine()` waits for the user to press "Enter" on the keyboard; it will block forever until that happens.

If you really want that things happen "automatically", you will need a more complex solution; for example you can wait for user input in a separate thread; and if there is no input after a given amount of time, your other thread can start doing "whatever" "automatically".

Answer (score 0):

Please tell the user to hit return after his input and check for empty lines like this:

```
if("".equals(input)){ //skip control
}
else{   //do something on input
}
```